# How to solve : $(3x+5)\Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big)^2-(3y+x)\Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big)+y=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

How to solve this ordinary differential equation?

$$
(3x+5)\Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big)^2-(3y+x)\Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big)+y=0
$$

How to find the **general solution** and **singular solution** of this differential equation?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p = \frac{dy}{dx}$. Therefore the differential equation is,
$$(3x+5)p^2-(3y+x)p+y=0$$
Differentiating with respect to x,
$$3p^2+6xp\frac{dp}{dx}+10p\frac{dp}{dx}-3p^2-3y\frac{dp}{dx}-p-x\frac{dp}{dx}+p=0$$
$$\therefore 6xp\frac{dp}{dx}+10p\frac{dp}{dx}-3y\frac{dp}{dx}-x\frac{dp}{dx}=0$$
$$\therefore \frac{dp}{dx}=0 \implies p =C$$ 
where C is an arbitrary constant or,
$$6xp+10p-3y-x=0 \implies p=\frac{3y+x}{6x+10}$$
Substituting the first relation in the original equation gives us the family of curves, 
$$y=\frac{(3x+5)C^2-Cx}{3C-1}$$
And substituting the second relation gives us the singular solution to be
$$y=\frac{(x+3y)^2}{4(3x+5)}$$

Comment: The expression we started with was also an ODE. Did you mean to say linear?

Comment: Oh yeah! I'll edit it. Thank you!

Comment: @AdityaSriram Can singular solution also contains arbitrary constants?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, it seems in the rush to submit the post, I made a blunder. I have fixed the problem, and you were absolutely right, the singular solution cannot contain arbitrary constants :)